# Passing and accessing multiple parameters to pthread function

Tags: c++, pthreads

I am a beginner to cpp and threads. Referred to some code snippets in stackoverflow to pass multiple arguments to a pthread function and came up with the below code. I am not sure how to access the struct members inside the function using (void*) pointer passed to it. Can anyone explain?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct a{
vector <int> v1;
int val;
};

void* function(void *args)
{
 vector <int>functionvector = (vector <int>)args->v1;
 functionvector.push_back(args->val);
 return NULL;
}


int main()
{
  pthread_t thread;
  struct a args;

  pthread_create(&thread, NULL, &function, (void *)&args);
  pthread_join(thread,NULL);
  for(auto it : args.v1)
  {
    cout<<it;
   }

  return 0;
}
```

Getting the error :
 error: ‘void*’ is not a pointer-to-object type

Comment: You must cast back to the type you casted from. `&args` is an `a*`.

Comment: Use std::thread, not pthreads.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot access the members of `a` until you have cast the `void*` back to an `a*`.

```
void* function(void *ptr)
{
 a* args = static_cast<a*>(ptr);

 args->v1.push_back(args->val);
 return NULL;
}
```

Comment: Oops! Got it! Thanks.